# How can I plot excel large Dataset with matplotlib not starting with first index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot excel data with Timestamp and another column.
x=Time
y='find'

Excel looks like this:

Read_in.xlsx:

```
Index    Timestamp              Find
0                             
1                              *useless information*
2        Timestamp             *useless information'  
3      2012-07-16 12:00:00      2,31
4      2012-07-16 12:05:00      2,33
5      2012-07-16 12:10:00      2,22
...
1447    2012-07-21 12:00:00     2,44
```

I've tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datei= pd.read_excel('Read_in.xlsx', sheet_name= 'Data')

daten=datei.filter(regex='Find')
Time=datei['Timestamp']
Time=Time.dropna(axis=0)
Time=Time.to_string()

x=Time
y= daten
plt.plot(x,y)
```

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (1448, 2)

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP4To.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace nopn datetimelike values to `NaT` and then [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for replace `,` to `.`:

```
datei['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(datei['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')
datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')
#if format of numbesr is 2.31 
#datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'], errors='coerce')
datei = datei.dropna()
print (datei)
            Timestamp  Find
3 2012-07-16 12:00:00  2.31
4 2012-07-16 12:05:00  2.33
5 2012-07-16 12:10:00  2.22
```

---

```
datei.plot(x='Timestamp', y='Find')
```

Or:

```
x=datei['Timestamp']
y= datei['Find']
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael for you answer. unfortunately the Dataframe shows empty : Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Timestamp, Unnamed: 1, Find, Unnamed: 3, Unnamed:4 ...] Index:[] [0 rows x 136 columns]

Comment: @jayjay62 - I think problem is with `2,44` - is format same in your data? Also `datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'].str.replace(',','.').str.strip(), errors='coerce')` working?

Comment: the format is almost the same like 2,44 but before this data starts this *useless information* is like this (from top to bottom) : Find (empty); 2,49; 0,12; 3PDF.pd; BAR TEE&Reaction  and now we got the Data coming 2,44..  datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'].str.replace(',','.').str.strip(), errors='coerce') showing empty dataframe

Comment: @jayjay62 - if remove `datei = datei.dropna()` then get missing values in timestamp or in find ?

Comment: I get the whole excel sheet including timestamp and all the columns except the column of 'Find' (just the topic of column find)

Comment: @jayjay62 - I got idea - change `datei = datei.dropna()` to `datei = datei.dropna(subset=['Timestamp','Find'])`

Comment: `datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')` --> `print(datei['Find']`--> out: Nan Nan Nan `datei = datei.dropna(subset=['Timestamp','Find'])` --> emptay DataFrame including all columns.. maybe there is a poyyibilitya do chage `daten=datei.filter(regex='Find')`? andd at the end * pd.concat*

Comment: @jayjay62 - Problem is for all values? What is `print(datei['Find'])` before `datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: `print(datei['Find'])`is after `datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')´ .so what is the main Problem here? What do you think. maybe i can try out more things if i know the problem. don't want to bother you so much

Comment: @jayjay62 - Are data confidental? If not, is possible share it?

Comment: unfortunately this case is something i have to do according to my job. so its confidential.. but i will try to figure it out..

Comment: @jayjay62 - there is some problem with numbers, check it by `print(datei['Find'].tolist())` before ` pd.to_numeri`

Comment: for ´print(datei['Find'].tolist())' i get printed out all values of that column, string an float numbers. number is like 2.333 (not 2,33)

Comment: @jayjay62 - so change `datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')` to `datei['Find'] = pd.to_numeric(datei['Find'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: Now it worked!! amazing!! Thank you very much for your kind help jezrael